# jQuery resizable se handle position

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, resizable

I made a div re-sizable with custom handles. Everything is working fine, but was wondering if there is a way to modify the position of the "se" handle. It's default location is inside of the div while the other handles are positioned on the outside of the div. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/digitalaxis/aLxjF/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the css:

```
.ui-resizable-se {
    right: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
}
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion...
#segrip {
    position: absolute;
    right: -6px;
    bottom: -6px;
}

Comment: Thanks guys! This really helps... couldn't find anything on this!